# difference between jquery live('submit') and submit in rails

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two very similar pieces of code, one works and the other doesnt:
This one works:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  return $("form#myform").live("submit", function() {
    var valuesToSubmit;
    valuesToSubmit = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
      url: $(this).attr("action"),
      data: valuesToSubmit,
      dataType: "JSON",
      success: function(json) {
        return $("#form-container").html(json["text"]);
      },
      error: function(json, xy, mycode) {
        var msg, response;
        response = $.parseJSON(json.responseText);
        msg = response.text;
        return alert(msg);
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

whereas this doesnt:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  return $("form#myform").submit(function() {
   //same stuff as before        

  });
});
```

Now the rails controller responds with json only, there is not html response. the difference i see in the two is, that both submit to the controller fine, but in the first case, the request is json as it should be, and the response is json, so it works fine. but in the second case, the request is of type html even though i specify 'dataType: "JSON"', the response is html and i get redirected to the form action page, and when i press the back button to navigate to the same page, i am logged out. so i want to know why navigating to back page logs me out as well.

so what is the difference in $(somthing).submit(function(){}); and $(somthing).live('submit', function(){}). they both are posting to the action, but one is creating a html request whereas the other is creating a json request, and one actually logs me out from the app, and the otehr does not?

Answer (score 0):

`.submit` calls `.bind` on the element itself, while `.live` attaches the event listener to the document and waits for it to bubble. In affect, if you delete the element and create a new, identical one, listeners added using `bind` will be deleted while listeners added using `.live` won't.

We can't answer the question with the amount of information that you have given us. Try logging `valuesToSubmit` to the console and seeing if there are any differences there (if there are differences and you don't know why it is affecting anything, post back here and we can help).

`.live` and `.bind` were both deprecated in version 1.7, you should consider upgrading and seeing what happens. There is also no need to return a value. You would want the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('submit', 'form#myform', function() {
   //same stuff as before        

  });
});
```